# How to add cookies to request in Restsharp?

Tags: c#, restsharp

I tried:

- `request.AddHeader("Cookie", ....`
- `request.AddCookie`
- `request.AddParameter("","",ParameterType.Cookie)`.

I sniff the network but the cookies don't send.

Answer (score 4):

You need to add the cookies to the `RestRequest` object.

```
var client = new RestClient("<server_url>");
var request = new RestRequest("<resource_url>", Method.GET);
request.AddCookie("cookie_name", "cookie_value");
request.AddCookie("cookie_name2", "cookie_value2");
var result = client.Execute(request);
```

Find more info about [AddCookie](https://restsharp.dev/v107/#reference) API

Comment: Alhamdulillah. Thanks a lot. Finally, I solved it. Dot net core is smart but it is working in asp.net

Comment: Sorry, I was not the question initiator.

Comment: It seems that RestRequest does not provide such method.

Comment: Check my link - updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
var authCookie = "name1=value1;name2=value2"
request.AddHeader("Cookie", authCookie);
```

The other ways including work with CookieContainer did't work for me